# How to hide the dropdown in docusaurus navbar after clicking a particular option

Tags: docusaurus

I am trying to build a docusaurus site which has a dropdown linked to sidebar. Upon clicking a metallic dropdown I want to hide that dropdown. Is it possible to achieve this?

My docusaurus.config.js

```
const CONSTANTS = require("./constants");

module.exports = {
  title: CONSTANTS.APP_TITLE,
  tagline: 'REST API Reference',
  url: '',
  baseUrl: '/',
  onBrokenLinks: 'warn',
  favicon: 'img/favicon.png',
  organizationName: '', // Usually your GitHub org/user name.
  projectName: 'webdocs', // Usually your repo name.
  themeConfig: {
    navbar: {
      title: CONSTANTS.APP_TITLE,
      logo: {
        alt: CONSTANTS.APP_TITLE,
        src: 'img/logo.svg',
      },
      items: [
        {
          type: 'docsVersionDropdown',
          position: 'right',
        },
        {
          type: "dropdown",
          label: 'Commcell Type',
          position: 'right',
          items: [{
            label: 'OnPrem',
            type: 'docSidebar',
            sidebarId: "OnPrem"
          }, {
            label: 'Metallic',
            type: 'docSidebar',
            sidebarId: "Metallic"
          }]
        },

      ],
    },
    "colorMode": {
      "defaultMode": "light",
      "disableSwitch": false,
      "respectPrefersColorScheme": false
    },
  },
  plugins: [
    ...
  ],
  themes: ["docusaurus-theme-openapi-docs" ,'@easyops-cn/docusaurus-search-local'],
  presets: [
    [
      '@docusaurus/preset-classic',
      {
        debug: true,
        docs: {
          
          sidebarPath: require.resolve('./sidebars.js'),
          editUrl: 'https://git.commvault.com/eng/docs/webdocs',
          docLayoutComponent: "@theme/DocPage",
          docItemComponent: "@theme/ApiItem"
        },
        blog: {
          showReadingTime: true,
          editUrl: 'https://github.com/facebook/docusaurus/edit/master/website/blog/',
        },
        theme: {
          customCss: require.resolve('./src/css/custom.css'),
        },
      },
    ]
  ],
};
```

Currently dropdown stays in navbar all the time. Looking for customizing that dropdown in navbar